# how to repeat code in if statement inside event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering how I can make my code repeat, actually how the square can move next 10px. When I press "d" key, the square mooves, but when i click on it again, nothing happens. It's because I set the position to 10px, but I cant figure out new naw how to do it.

My code:

```
let body = document.querySelector("body")
body.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
console.log(event.key)


if(event.key == "d"){
   
   console.log("something")
   let cube = document.getElementById("cube")
   cube.style.left = "10px"
}
})
```

Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: `cube.style.left` doesn't make it move 10px to the left; it positions it so that its left side is at 10px on the grid. Thus clicking again keeps it at the same position.

Comment: You might need to keep count of how many times the key was pressed and multiply by 10 to set `style.left`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let body = document.querySelector("body")
body.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
console.log(event.key)


if(event.key == "d"){
   
   console.log("something")
   let cube = document.getElementById("cube");
   const left = cube.style.left || 0;
   cube.style.left = `${parseInt(left) + 10}px`;
}
})
```

```css
#cube {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="cube">
</div>
```

Comment: Gavriolov Thank you for that! Anyways, how can I make the same code, but with cube mooving to the right? I tried it on my own, but although I didnt make it.

Answer (score 1):

If `cube.style.left = "10px"` works as expected for the first click, so it set left property to `10px`. In this case, you need to add `10px` to current `Xpx`. Hope this code help you

```
if(event.key == "d"){
    console.log("something")
    let cube = document.getElementById("cube")
    cube.style.left = `${(parseInt(cube.style.left) + 10) || 0}px`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you don't move the box by 10px to the left everytime you press d but you apply it **once**. To apply it multiple times you should use a variable that you keep increasing by every button press.

PS: You don't need to use `querySelector('body')` as you can simply address it with `body` directly:

```js
let left_multiplier = 0;

document.body.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
  console.log(event.key);
  if(event.key == "d"){
    left_multiplier++;
    let cube = document.getElementById("cube")
    cube.style.left = `${left_multiplier * 10}px`;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable and store what the current offset position is

Everytime you press "D" you add 10 to the variable.

```
let leftOffset = 0;

let body = document.querySelector("body")
body.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if(event.key == "d") {
     let cube = document.getElementById("cube")
     leftOffset += 10;
     cube.style.left = `${leftOffset}px`;
  }
})
```

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0yobp14h/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let body = document.querySelector("body")
let value = 0

body.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
  if(event.key == "d"){
    let cube = document.getElementById("cube")
    value += 10
    cube.style.marginLeft = value + 10 + 'px'
  }
})
```

When you put `cube.style.left = "10px"` you are fixing a value to the style.
But when you do:

```js
value += 10
cube.style.marginLeft = value + 10 + 'px'
```

You are dynamically updating the style in each key event